# Линия после блоков

Tags: html, css

Имеется несколько блоков с фиксированной шириной. Как сделать, чтобы после каждого блока отображалась горизонтальная линия на всю ширину, вне зависимости от высоты блоков?

[image: img]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/u75BA/

```css
.block {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:#dfdfdf;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.wrapper {
    margin:20px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    border-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"><div class="block"></div></div>
<div class="wrapper"><div class="block"></div></div>
<div class="wrapper"><div class="block"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделать линию бэкграундом у блоков, расположив снизу

```
div {
background: url(../images/line.png) center bottom repeat-x;
}
```

или задать

```
div {
border-bottom: 1ps solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

мне кажется самое верное решение тут это [`<hr />`](http://htmlbook.ru/html/hr)